# Qt 5.4 supported .so files come with default Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty or not

Tags: 14.04, deb, qt5

I am able to make deb file of Qt 5.2.1 app but not Qt 5.4 app in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64 bit.

I have seen that Qt .so files present at the path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` are Qt 5.2.1 compatible not the Qt 5.4 compatible.

So I just want to know that which Qt version compatible `.so` files come with default Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty and if it not Qt 5.4 compatible then how can I make it Qt 5.4 compatible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The repository for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS currently contains files for Qt5 up to version 5.2.1

Every time there is a new release, the Ubuntu team will have to make sure that this new version is integrated into the repository. But usually only bugfixes and minor features get adopted into older Linux Versions.

14.04 is a Long Term Support release, so it gets updates for longer, but I'm not sure if it will get the latest Qt. Also, that release is pretty new, so it will take a while until it lands in the repository.

So there is no easy way to do what you want. I assume you now quite a bit about [packaging](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/), since you said you packaged an app already. Maybe [a PPA](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/other-forms-of-submitting-apps/ppa/) could be a solution. You could provide a package for Qt5.4 and one for your app. Maybe there is already a Qt PPA, but I couldn't find one.

Edit: Maybe [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~beineri/+archive/ubuntu/opt-qt541-trusty)

Answer (score 1):

You can get the version of the software you have installed either within the software center or searching ubuntu packages

http://packages.ubuntu.com/

qt5 is version 5.2 in Ubuntu 14.04

http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/qt5-default

the files in qt5.2 are not compatible with the files in qt5.4

If you want a version of qt not in the ubuntu repositores you need to manually install it.

There are instructions here :

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

http://musescore.org/en/developers-handbook/compilation/compile-instructions-ubuntu-12.04-git

http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_Qt_5_from_Git

I have not seen a ppa for this and most of the build instructions use Qt5.2 or 5.3.

You can try the last link, building from git, but I am not sure if it works. I tried building 5.3 in Ubuntu 14.04 without success, so, can not confirm that it is possible.

If you "must have" qt5.4 you may need to use a higher version of Ubuntu (15.04)

http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/qt5-default

or an alternate distro. Fedora has qt5.4 in the repos - https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/qt5-qtbase